# Regex for matching a US phone number

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have written my first regex:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string phoneNumber= Console.ReadLine();

    Regex pattern = new Regex("(1-)?\\p{N}{3}-\\p{N}{3}-\\p{N}{4}\\b");

    MatchCollection collection = pattern.Matches(phoneNumber);

    Console.WriteLine(phoneNumber + " is " + (collection.Count == 1 && collection[0].ToString() == phoneNumber ? "" : "not ") + "a valid US number.");
}
```

It needs to match the entire input string, and it can work for any US phone number with or without country code "1-". It can most likely be improved; any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use of Regex Objects

If your intent is merely to validate that the input is a phone number or not, rather than trying to capture anything, you can use the static [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
var isPhoneNumber = Regex.IsMatch(phoneNumber, "(1-)?\\p{N}{3}-\\p{N}{3}-\\p{N}{4}\\b");
```

That saves having to deal with creating a new object and deal with a `MatchCollection`

### Regex Pattern

There are a few things I would change:

- There is a simple character class for matching digits 0-9: `\d`.  `\p{N}` may be more appropriate if you need to match the entire Unicode number group rather than simple digits, but then I would not expect to see the explicit `1` at the start.
- `\b` matches backspace characters, which seems a little odd in a phone number.  I would omit it.  If your phone number strings happen to have backspace characters at the end, it will still match, but I would not require it be there.
- Given the backslashes necessary for character escapes, I would prefix your string with the `@` symbol for readability

Also, as @miasbeck points out, if you want to match the entire input string, you need to prefix the pattern with `^` and suffix it with `$`.  They indicate that the match must start at the beginning and end of the string, respectively.

The end result would be something like the following:

```
@"^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$"
```

Additionally, since there is no requirement that an area code is used for local numbers, so you may want to make it optional as well:

```
@"^((1-)?\d{3}-)?\d{3}-\d{4}$"
```

(note: The MSDN page on [Regular Expression Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is always a good reference to check on when coming up with regex patterns in .NET code.)

### String Formatting

Rather than concatenating the strings together, I would use a format string:

```
const string FMT = "{0} is {1} a valid US number.";
```

Additionally, instead of using `""`, I always tend towards `string.Empty`, as it is much more explicit about intent.  `""` could easily be a mistake, but `string.Empty` is clear that you really do want an empty string.

You can then output your result as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(FMT, phoneNumber, (isPhoneNumber ? string.Empty : "not "));
```

### Bringing it Together

Taking all the suggestions together, you get the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   const string FMT = "{0} is {1} a valid US number.";
   var phoneNumber= Console.ReadLine();
   var isPhoneNumber = Regex.IsMatch(phoneNumber, @"^((1-)?\d{3}-)?\d{3}-\d{4}$");
   Console.WriteLine(FMT, phoneNumber, (isPhoneNumber ? string.Empty : "not "));
}
```

(note: I switch back and forth between C# and F# , so I use `var` more often than most - feel free to keep the explicit type declarations if you really want)

Comment: You may want to add ^ at the start and $ at the end of the pattern, because the OP asked to match the entire input string.

Comment: @miasbeck good point - I'll make the edit.